# Generate table and clickable images in Shiny R

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, shiny-server

I need to do the following in R:

1) Dynamically(for X images in ...) create a table/grid where I display them, for example in a 4xN table.

2) Make each of those images clickable, so that it feeds its name into a function in R. For example if we clicked on a monkey, it is supposed to call a function: selected(monkey.jpg).

Comment: I don't know, seems like a legit question to me. Thinking...

Comment: When you say "dynamically", will the images always be the same for the app? Or could the images change when you hit Reload in the browser, or could the list of images be reactive to an input or something? (It's doable any which way, just simpler code if the images will always be the same)

Comment: I mean, there are folders with images, and the UI should just populate it with them. Over time some images may be added, so each time the page is reloaded it should essentially count the images and scan the folders with a for loop. I know how to do the R part, I just dont know what to put in a loop in R to make it appear :).

Comment: @JoeCheng The mouseover text on the down vote arrow includes "does not show any research effort". That is interpreted by many on SO, particularly within the R tag, that the OP should display some sort of an attempt at a solution so that we have something concrete to help them with. Otherwise, questions quickly descend into just specifications for output that we are required to produce.

Comment: I asked the question in a way that could give an idea of me not making any research, but I really did. Provide me with some links if there is something I missed.

Comment: Look, I'm simply explaining why I think some people may have down voted (I did not). Your question contains no actual code that represents an attempted solution on your part. _That's_ how many people think of "research" here. Otherwise, as I mentioned, we are inundated with questions that consist of nothing more than "I need to build X, Y and Z. How do I do it?" which doesn't feel like a _question_ so much as a _demand_ for us to do work for others. I realize that may not have been your intent, but that is how many might see it.

Comment: Okay. I understand. Thanks for the insight :-). Normally I post failed code when it lacks a part, but in this case nothing was "compilable", hence I would easier understand downvoting in that case :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Feels like cheating but using a little JS is the easiest way.

In your ui.R, put this somewhere (like inside your mainPanel or whatever):

```
uiOutput("imageGrid"),
tags$script(HTML(
  "$(document).on('click', '.clickimg', function() {",
  "  Shiny.onInputChange('clickimg', $(this).data('value'));",
  "};"
))
```

In your server function:

```
output$imageGrid <- renderUI({
  fluidRow(
    lapply(images, function(img) {
      column(3, 
        tags$img(src=paste0("images/", img), class="clickimg", data-value=img)
      )
    })
  )
})
```

Then in your server function you can access `input$clickimg` to determine the last clicked images. Keep in mind this'll be a reactive value (just like any other input), so you have to access it from within a reactive expression or output rendering function (or observer if you're a more advanced Shiny user). Oh and the initial value will be `NULL` so don't forget to check for that too.

Comment: Wait, I just realized that this is asking in general for R, not specifically for Shiny. It might be easier to just use grid graphics and grid.locator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I still wonder if there is another way around it! Do you know of any sources, tutorials that would possibly explain the non-JS version(which is fine btw!).

Comment: I think one should change line 5 in ui.R to `"});"` and  `data-value=img` to `'data-value'=img` in server.ui. Anyways, very useful!